# Custom pandoc writer in lua: attempt to call nil value

Tags: lua, latex, markdown, pandoc

I'm trying to set up a simple custom writer going from `pandoc`'s markdown to latex. Here's what I have so far:

## test.md

```
# A section

## A subsection


Heres a paragraph.


Heres another
```

## custom_writer.lua

```
function Header(lev, s, attr)
    level_sequences = {
        "section",
        "subsection",
        "subsubsection",
        "subsubsubsection"
    }
    return string.format("\\%s{%s}", level_sequences[lev], s)
end

function Para(s)
    return s.."\\parskip"
end

function Str(s)
    return s
end

function Space()
    return " "
end
```

## Question

As far as I understand from the [docs](https://pandoc.org/custom-writers.html)

> A writer using the classic style defines rendering functions for each element of the pandoc AST

I checked the resulting JSON from my markdown file and the only the following elements occur:

- Header
- Para
- Str
- Space

It seems to my that I've covered all the necessary elements in the AST, so I'm not sure why `pandoc` complains with `Error running lua: attempt to call a nil value` when I do the following:

`pandoc test.md -t custom_writer.lua`

Does anyone know what I'm missing in `custom_writer.lua`?

Comment: Should be enough to add `function Doc (body, meta, vars) return body end` to make it work.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing a few things which are not documented:

```
function Header(lev, s, attr)
    level_sequences = {
        "section",
        "subsection",
        "subsubsection",
        "subsubsubsection"
    }
    return string.format("\\%s{%s}", level_sequences[lev], s)
end

function Blocksep()
    return "\\parskip"
end

function Para(s)
    return s.."\\parskip"
end

function Str(s)
    return s
end

function Space()
    return " "
end

function Doc(body, metadata, variables) 
    return body
end
```